Discord Bot with Discord.py 2.0 - Unable to show image from assets parameter in discord.Streaming()
Currently using Discord 2.4.0 and Python 3.12.1
In my dev portal -> Rich Presence -> Rich Presence Assets I have uploaded a 1024x1024 jpg image and named it "asset_id". I made sure to save the changes and after refreshing the page the image is still there. However, when I click on my bot, the image does not show up. Instead I see a box with a question mark (kinda like the mystery box from Mario but black and white). The text does not show up when I hover over the image either. The name and url both work and update properly. Any suggestions to get the image to show up would be appreciated.
   await bot.change_presence(
        activity=discord.Streaming(name="Game", url=url, assets={
            "large_image": "asset_id",
            "large_text": "large text",
            "small_image": "asset_id",
            "small_text": "small text"}))



Ensure that image format is correct (PNG or JPEG)
Ensure your bot has the necessary permissions to set the presence. This is generally managed in the OAuth2 settings of your bot.


Rich presence with image(s) cannot be set with a bot currently.
